# Magento 2.3.2 - display text/attribute in product listing page(catalogue page)

Tags: magento2.3.2

I want to display attribute(sku) on product listing page in magento 2.3.2. I have tried to code on list.phtml file under public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product with no success. Please inform name and location of file where I need to code.

In magento 1.9.4 I can code in list.phtml file located under public_html/app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/catalog/product to achieve result.

But In Magento 2.3.2 coding in list.phtml file located under public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product is not working.

Can anyone please let me know where & how to code to display attribute sku on product listing page(catalogue page) in magento 2.3.2

thanks,

Comment: I already have enabled attribute(sku) visibility from backend to display in frontend. I want to get displayed sku value below price value in category page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1: You need to create a custom theme that inherits from Luma theme to override the file correctly.

> app/design/frontend/{vendor_namespace}/{theme_name}/registration.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::THEME,
    'frontend/{vendor_namespace}/{theme_name}',
    __DIR__
);
```

> app/design/frontend/{vendor_namespace}/{theme_name}/theme.xml

```
<theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd">
    <title>Your Custom Theme</title>
    <parent>Magento/luma</parent>
</theme>
```

Step 2: Now Override the vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list.phtml file.

> app/design/frontend/[Vendor]/[Theme]/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml

```
<?php SKU : echo ($_product->getSku() ?>
```

Comment: Yes I have created a custom theme that inherits from Blank theme. There were 2 3rd party theme - that I have removed and now it is displaying - perfectly.

Comment: Paresh, If you find my answer useful then please accept this as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

For fresh installation product listing template for category page is :

> vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list.phtml

Now you check under your active theme. If you installed a theme without composer then location should be:

> app/design/frontend/[YourVendorName]/[YourThemeName]/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml

If not working then looking for inside your custom module where this template overwrite.

***Note:*** SKU attribute **Used in Product Listing** property should be yes.
[image]

**[Update]**

I enable **Used in Product Listing** property for SKU, then added following line in list.phtml

```
SKU : <?= $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getSku(), 'sku') ?>
```

Now looks like:
[image]

**Don't forget to clear cache.**

Comment: if I code like .....  <h3><?php echo $this->__('SKU:') . $this->htmlEscape($_product->getData('sku'));?></h3>  .... in vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list.phtml will it displayed in case of luma theme....???

Comment: yes. Also, check the updated answer.

Comment: I already have enabled attribute(sku) visibility from backend to display in frontend. I want to get displayed sku value below price value in category page.

Comment: Below code I have used in list.phtml file 

</strong>
                        <?= $block->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, $templateType) ?>
                        <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getProductPrice($_product) ?>
                        <?= $block->getProductDetailsHtml($_product) ?>
                        
                        <h3><?php echo $this->__('SKU:') . $this->htmlEscape($_product->getData('sku'));?></h3>

But sku not displyed below price line in category page.   ????

Comment: Check updated answer.

Comment: I have done exactly same .... but no success ... in magento 2.3.2 luma theme... also cleared cache...

Comment: thank you very much Mr.Sohel Rana for your effort but I yet to solve the issue...

Comment: @Paresh are you using any third-party module or search which is extending/inherting the product list page?

Comment: Accepted Your Answer.