# Get attribute text not working

Tags: magento-2.1, php, magento2.3

getSku works but getAttributeText doesn't? I have tried setting sku as the attribute in AttributeText as I know it returns a result. Also tried getManufacturer.
`$xml .= $this->createNode("g:brand", $this->getAttributeText($product, 'manufacturer'));
        $xml .= $this->createNode("g:mpn", $product->getSku());`

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code may be help you :---

First you have to load the products

```
$_productCollection = $block->getLoadedProductCollection();
```

In the product listing page ,there will be a foreach loop for listing the products like this

```
foreach ($_productCollection as $_product)
```

Your code will be inside this loop.Place the below code at a place where ever you want to display the attribute label.

```
$_product->getResource()->getAttribute('your_attribute_code')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
```

And more refer this very helpful :--

**[how can i get the the attribute label from the attribute value in magento 2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/141360/how-can-i-get-the-the-attribute-label-from-the-attribute-value-in-magento-2)**

Thanks.

Comment: Hi below is how i have loaded the products. Your code works for attribute text but only for sku nothing else? Attributes visible on storefront set to yes. `public function getProductsXml()
    {
        $productCollection = $this->_productFeedHelper->getFilteredProducts();
        $xml = "";

        foreach ($productCollection as $product) {
            $xml .= "<item>" . $this->buildProductXml($product) . "</item>";
        }

        return $xml;
    }

    public function buildProductXml($product)
    {`

Comment: i don't understand your above comment so Please explain briefly...

Comment: `$product->getResource()->getAttribute('manufacturer')->getFrontend()->getValue($product);` returns no results. `$product->getResource()->getAttribute('sku')->getFrontend()->getValue($product);` returns result as expected.

Comment: you solve the issue ??

Comment: No because I need the attribute 'manufacturer' to return a result. I was thinking maybe it was the way I loaded the products.

Comment: SKU : <?= $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getSku(), 'sku') ?> try this

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/285711/magento-2-3-2-display-text-attribute-in-product-listing-pagecatalogue-page refer this

Comment: Seems to return a result for an attribute with Multiselect but not Dropdown?